# how to show array element one by one on page while array is property of an object which inside of services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this a testPaper object in Services :

```
this.testPapers=[{
        courseName: 'Languages' , moduleName: 'Arabic',
        paperName: 'Arabic-V',
        paperDate: '15/08/2014',
        // paperStartTime:
        //papertEndTime:
        // PaperDuration:     '00:10:00',
        marksForEachQuestion: 5,
        totalMarks: 15,
        Question: ['Mirwaha meaning in English?','Jwwaz meaning in English?','Hafila meaning in English?']

    }
```

while the controller:

```
  .controller('questionStart',function($scope, $routeParams,$rootScope,crudService){
  //          $scope.allCourses= crudService.courses;
//            $scope.allModules=crudService.modules;
            $scope.allTestPapers=crudService.testPapers;
}
```

and UI

```
 <ol>
            <li data-ng-repeat="p in allTestPapers | filter : mSelectedCourse
                                                   | filter:  mSelectedModule
                                                   | filter : mSelectedPaper">
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        Paper Name  :<b>{{p.paperName}}</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        Total Marks:<b>{{p.totalMarks}}</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        Marks For Each Question: <b>{{p.marksForEachQuestion}}</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        Total Question: <b>{{p.Question.length}}</b>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <hr>
                <h4>{{p.Question}}</h4>
<!--Which logic need to put in above line to not show all question at once instead one at a time
```

and when user click a button then next question will show??? how to do this-->

```
    <button data-ng-click="">next</button>

            </ol>
```

now from this i want to show the Question array on the page but one by one (mean from 0 to last item but one question show at page then on button click i want to change the question).
How can i do this;

Answer (score 0):

So here is how you should go on about it, starting from the UI, which will have a heading for question, an input box for answer and a next button:

```
<h3 id='q'>Questions will appear here<h3>
Answer: <input type:'text' id='a'><br>
<button onclick="showQuestion()">Next</button>
```

Then your tesPapers, for this example i used two papers:

```
var testPapers = [{
        courseName: 'Languages' , moduleName: 'Arabic',
        paperName: 'Arabic-V',
        paperDate: '15/08/2014',
        // paperStartTime:
        //papertEndTime:
        // PaperDuration:     '00:10:00',
        marksForEachQuestion: 5,
        totalMarks: 15,
        Question: ['Mirwaha meaning in English?','Jwwaz meaning in English?','Hafila meaning in English?']
},{
        courseName: 'Languages' , moduleName: 'Arabic',
        paperName: 'Arabic-V',
        paperDate: '15/08/2014',
        // paperStartTime:
        //papertEndTime:
        // PaperDuration:     '00:10:00',
        marksForEachQuestion: 5,
        totalMarks: 15,
        Question: ['Mirwaha meaning in English?','Jwwaz meaning in English?','Hafila meaning in English?']
}];
```

Now all the question logic, its simple.. you need to have two counters, one for paperNumber other for Question number.. when current paper's questions end, you need to increment the paperNumber and when all papers end, simply display End of all papers.

```
var paperNumber = 0;
var questionNumber = 0;
function showQuestion(){
    document.getElementById('q').innerHTML = testPapers[paperNumber].Question[questionNumber];
    questionNumber++;
    if(questionNumber > testPapers[paperNumber].Question.length){
        document.getElementById('q').innerHTML = "End of this Paper";
        questionNumber = 0;
        paperNumber++;
        if(paperNumber >= testPapers.length){
                    document.getElementById('q').innerHTML = "End of All Papers";
        }
    }
}
```

OfCourse you can change the UI however you want but the core logic should remain the same, specially the question and papers looping mechanism.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/o9rp5znz/)**

Comment: I am using Angular JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the service into the controller for the required view. Then you should be able to use the ng-repeat directive:

```
<p ng-repeat="quest in serviceName.testPaper[0].Question">{{quest}}</p>
```

edit as per comments:
in controller:

```
var index = 0;
$scope.currentQuestion = serviceName.testPaper[0].Question[index];
$scope.nextQuestion = function() {
  $scope.currentQuestion = serviceName.testPaper[0].Question[index+1];
};
```

in html

```
<p>{{currentQuestion}}</p>
<button ng-click="nextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
```

Comment: i have already inject it this is not the question. I want to show Question element one by one on page

Comment: please see my edited answer. The ng-repeat directive loops through the Question array creating a paragraph html element (or whatever element you want) for each item in the array

Comment: this will show all at once i want to show one by one. have updated my question